# Pass a System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex as function parameter in Powershell 6

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

Hello Powershell Experts,

I want to write a Powershell function that takes a System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex as a parameter. My function header goes like this:

```
function Foo {
    Param([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex] $myRegex)
    # function body
}
```

And I tried to call `Foo` like this:

```
$MY_REGEX = new-object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex('<regex_body>')
Foo($MY_REGEX)
```

I got an error that says `Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type 
"System.Object[]" to type "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex".`

I'm wondered why this is since I explicitly defined the regex with `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` type. So I did .GetType() on my object and I got:

```
BaseType                   : System.Object
UnderlyingSystemType       : System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
FullName                   : System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
```

So now I'm confused why it's complaining about casting when the underlying type matches...

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]? My wild guess: your `Foo` have multiple parameters and you call it wrong: `Foo($param1, $param2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line the below works for me with a bit of the relevant output provided.  Can you provide an full example.

```
function foo { param ( [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex] $myRegex ) ; process { Write-Information -MessageData $myRegex -InformationAction Continue ; $myRegEx.GetType() | fl * } }
foo a.
$r = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx("a.")
foo -MyRegex $r
```

and emits

```
a.

FullName                   : System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
```

Try using the last syntax shown.

Comment: I called the function using your syntax and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped.  For future readers and powershell noobs, function calling syntax is either by positional parameter or, preferably by using named parameters as suggested by this answer.  Removing parentheses and using named parameters can go a long way toward debugging mystery output from functions